# How to show Number of users connected in pubnub using presence and subscribe method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, pubnub, subscribe, unsubscribe

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Currently Active Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .currently-active {
      position: fixed;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      border: solid 1px #AFAFAF;
      border-radius: 6px;
      font-family: "Arial";
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="currently-active">
    <span>Currently Active: </span><span id="active"></span>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.20.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var active = document.getElementById('active');
function setCurrentlyActiveUsers(numberOfUsers) {
  active.innerText = numberOfUsers.toString();
}
setCurrentlyActiveUsers(1);
var pubnub = new PubNub({
 publishKey: 'pub-demo',
    subscribeKey: 'sub-demo',
    heartbeatInterval: 30
});
pubnub.addListener({
  presence: function(presenceEvent) {
    console.log("Occupancy "+presenceEvent.occupancy);
    console.log("Action "+presenceEvent.action);
    setCurrentlyActiveUsers(presenceEvent.occupancy);
  }
});
pubnub.subscribe({ 
  channels: ['myWebPage1'],
  withPresence: true
});
</script>
</html>
```

I have written a code to show the real-time total number of users connected in core JS using PubNub. But the problem I am facing is I am unable to get the accurate number. Sometimes When I have just executed the code I will get currently active user 0 and sometimes one. The problem lies in Presence action join and leave but I don't know how automatically sometimes I get presence action value as join and sometimes as leave and that too is random. Please help me resolve this issue so that I can get a concurrent number of active users who are connected in real-time and the number increase or decrease accordingly

Comment: First, you shouldn't show your pub/sub keys. Please redact them. Second, how are you connecting other users/clients to your channel?

Comment: Hi @CraigConover, sure I have removed the pub/sub keys and I am connecting them using the same code. What I am doing is opening the same code in multiple browsers and its value is updating i.e. incrementing on opening the same link in a new browser and decrementing when closing the browser. But the value is not accurate sometimes when I have opened it only on a single browser it shows 0 but sometimes it shows 1 I don't know why it is happening so

Comment: That's because there is async stuff happening. When you subscribe to a channel, a join gets sent out and the occupancy gets incremented for that channel on PN network. But that join event is sent before that counter is incremented, sometimes. It's just an async race condition and should only affect the joining client. All other clients should just get the join and you the proper count. Let me know.

Comment: @CraigConover can you please show me the demonstration you can use my above code as well if you want

Comment: I would just recommend doing the [JS SDK Getting](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/quickstarts/javascript) Started and then reading through all the other docs there. I think it will provide insights you are looking for and more.